# Active Record Subtract Two values with different where statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to wrap my head around the correct rails way to do this.  I have two tables,  one is players who has a one to many relationship to dailystats table.  Each day, new stats are recorded.  I'm trying to take the top stat for only that month, but the stats are recorded overall.  So todays stats are the total of all months.  So I need to take the current month and subtract it from the last day of the previous month.

I use the following to get the top stat for the current day.

```
@gamesplayed = Player.joins(:dailystats).select('players.*, dailystats.gamesplayed AS average_score').order('average_score desc').group('players.id').where('MONTH(statdate) = MONTH(NOW())').first.name
```

So how would I do it for top player from the difference of this month - last month?  I would assume it would look something like this,

```
@gamesplayed = (Player.joins(:dailystats).select('players.*, dailystats.gamesplayed AS average_score').where('(MONTH(statdate) = MONTH(NOW()))') -  Player.joins(:dailystats).select('players.*, dailystats.gamesplayed AS average_score').where('(MONTH(statdate) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')).first.name
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work or are you asking for a better solution? For the latter, changing how you store the data will make it for an optimized single query. If you store the incremental change, rather than the accumulated it will make it easier to retrieve.

Answer (score 2):

You could run two queries, like your suggested solution has, but the `-` operator is definitely not smart enough to handle computing the row-wise difference of each of them. You'd have to write your own code to iterate through each "this month" row, find the corresponding "last month" row, and store the difference.

But you can also do this in one query. It's going to get complicated to do so within Rails' query syntax, as we're getting into relatively advanced SQL here, but I'll do my best.

```
Player
  .joins("JOIN (SELECT player_id,
            SUM(gamesplayed) as gamesplayed, COUNT(*) as count
            FROM dailystats
            WHERE DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', statdate) = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', NOW())
            GROUP BY player_id) this_month
          ON this_month.player_id = players.id 
        ")
  .joins("JOIN (SELECT player_id,
            SUM(gamesplayed) as gamesplayed, COUNT(*) as count
            FROM dailystats
            WHERE DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', statdate) = 
              DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', NOW() - INTERVAL '1 month')
            GROUP BY player_id) last_month
          ON last_month.player_id = players.id 
        ")
   .select('players.*')
   .select('this_month.gamesplayed - last_month.gamesplayed AS gamesplayed_change')
```

(You might notice I changed your `MONTH()` usage to `DATE_TRUNC('month')`; the reason for that is MONTH will return 1, 2, 3, 4, etc., which means if your site runs for longer than a year you'll start getting back last year's data mixed in inappropriately.)

The way the above works is by joining onto the dailystats table twice; once for stats in this month, and once for stats in last month. However, since there are multiple dailystats entries for each player, we first group up each months' stats via a subquery, such that we expect just one such row of each to be joined onto each player. Then, our SELECT clause can use the monthly stats we computed above to get a reasonable difference.

Now, that code above is too long to just drop into your codebase. To clean it up, you may want to create a monthlystats roll-up table (which could be implemented as a view in your database), or convert your code to using raw SQL (extracted to a separate module).

P.S. The above code is untested, and as such probably contains a bug or two. Please comment if it doesn't work and I'll help resolve.